How does blender implement its attribute blending for edge collapses?
I am curious as to how blender merges attributes (normals, uvs...) through its decimation process.
So I tried looking at the source code. The function where they get blended seems to be:
CustomData_bmesh_interp_n, here.
void CustomData_bmesh_interp_n(CustomData *data,
                               const void **src_blocks_ofs,
                               const float *weights,
                               const float *sub_weights,
                               int count,
                               void *dst_block_ofs,
                               int n)
{
  BLI_assert(weights != nullptr);
  BLI_assert(count > 0);

  CustomDataLayer *layer = &data->layers[n];
  const LayerTypeInfo *typeInfo = layerType_getInfo(layer->type);

  typeInfo->interp(src_blocks_ofs, weights, sub_weights, count, dst_block_ofs);
}

All this does is get some weights and defer to another call.
I am having issues:

Locating the specific interp function that's getting called, because it's a very common word in the project, making grepping for it challenging.
Understanding how it is handling discontinuities in the attributes.


Have you tried contacting the folks that work on Blender?

Yes, and that's how I got this function. But they are busy and this is as far as they got me.

The interp function isn't some random function in any part of the project. It's specifically a method of the LayerTypeInfo class. So you should begin by locating the definition of that class, and if you're lucky it'll be an actual member function instead of a lambda. If you're very lucky, that class won't be a superclass for some unknown derived class that provides the specific implementation you're looking for. I would begin by grepping for LayerTypeInfo::interp as a whole word.

It's a function pointer, and i cannot find the definition of layerType_getInfo so I have no idea how that pointer is initialized.

A quick search of GitHub finds the definition here, with the LAYERTYPEINFO table defined in the same file.
